# How to Resize a Grid exactly as the size Origninal canvas when Window is Maximized

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol, mahapps.metro

I'm very new to using WPF and having a problem on how to responsively resize the Grids when I set the Window State to *maximized*.

Please take a look on the design on the canvas when **not Maximized**:

http://imageshack.com/a/img921/3706/3E8e1F.png

and here's the look of **Maximized** window:

http://imageshack.com/a/img922/9510/0f2Dsq.png

Comment: Did you set the width and height of the canvas explicitly?

Comment: @Meloviz sir I set it into Auto

Comment: Some code would be useful. What's it's Horizontal and Vertical Alignment? What are the margins set to? What's it's parent, and what are the size settings of that?

Comment: The XAML of TabControl sir: 

<TabControl  Margin="14,62,3.4,8.2" TabStripPlacement="Left" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">

Comment: Is your Canvas in a Grid? It really would be helpful if you could show us the complete control from Window down to your control. You can leave out extraneous code that isn't pertinent to your problem, but troubleshooting is much harder without seeing code.

Comment: I have a feeling that somewhere along the lines from the Window to your Canvas, the height and width are set explicitly. So, one of the parent controls is probably where your issue lies. Canvases should resize to fill the entirety of their parent control.

Comment: As above, it's very hard to find problems with little snippets of code posted in comments - put this in your question. But from what you have put: You have set the horizontal and vertical alignment of your tab control to top, left. So it's in the top left. Try setting them as "Stretch".

Answer (score 0):

1. set HorizontalAlignment="Streach" and VerticalAlignment="Streach"
2. remove harcoded height and width value.
3. Instead you can set MinHeight, MinWidth if required.
4. set margin accordingly if any set.